# Checks against corruption in Gaza, and their effectiveness

Tags: palestine, corruption, hamas

What checks to corruption (if any) are there to the Hamas regime in Gaza, and how effective are they?

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption) quoting the World Bank, corruption "is a form of dishonesty or a criminal offense which is undertaken by a person or an organization which is entrusted with a position of authority, in order to acquire illicit benefits or abuse power for one's private gain."

---

<sub>**Related:** [Checks against corruption in the Palestinian Authority and their effectiveness](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/64174)</sub>

Comment: What do you mean by “checks to corruption”? Are you asking how Hamas investigates and punishes corruption?

Comment: @divibisan Not specifically Hamas. If in Gaza there was a "free parliament, free press, and civil society organizations" that could hold the Hamas government accountable, then those would certainly be part of the checks. But I don't think that's the case (I'd be glad to be proven wrong). Saying Hamas holds itself accountable is a rather ridiculous statement, given the nature of the Hamas regime. I'm asking more broadly: what factors/mechanisms prevents Hamas leaders from slipping their hands into the public till, or at least, from doing it too often?

Comment: What do you mean by "corruption"?  Would diverting funds meant for humanitarian purposes to production of weapons to use against Israel be considered corruption?

Comment: @jamessqf Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corruption) quoting the World Bank, corruption "is a form of dishonesty or a criminal offense which is undertaken by a person or an organization which is entrusted with a position of authority, in order to acquire illicit benefits or abuse power for one's private gain." If we assume prioritizing weapons production over humanitarian purposes is not in the interests of the Palestinian people, I think it would follow that said prioritization is for some private gain, and thus would fall under this definition of corruption.

Comment: @ZevSpitz You suggest that *if* Hamas does not act in the best interests of the Palestinian people *then* it is corrupt. That seems to presuppose a rather Western view of government, with some flavor of democracy. Why should it be Hamas' purpose to act in the best interest of the Palestinian people?

Comment: @user44105 A non-democractic governing institution could explicitly see its mandate as making the "right" choice to save the people from itself (e.g. the unelected activist Israeli Supreme Court, which reserves for itself the authority to review all laws passed by the democratically elected Knesset, in accordance with its own "enlightened" principles). Hamas could in theory argue that prioritizing weapons production is for the benefit of the Palestinian people, even if the people would prefer peace with Israel -- which is why I labelled the inverse as an assumption in a previous comment.

Comment: @user44105 Hamas might present its corruption-like activities generally in the same vein, as somehow being good for the Palestinian people. But checks on corruption -- whether coming from democratic or non-democratic institutions -- would ensure that Hamas would have to live up to these claims.

Answer (score -1):

There really aren't any, because the media, the UN, and most countries are super-supportive of Hamas and the PA and Hamas.

Somebody asked for sources:

UNRWA schools are used as Hamas bases (https://unwatch.org/un-admits-palestinians-fired-rockets-unrwa-schools/, https://www.jpost.com/arab-israeli-conflict/unrwa-discovers-hamas-tunnel-under-gaza-schools-496394), their funds are used to build terror infrastructure (https://www.jewishpolicycenter.org/2007/08/31/how-unrwa-supports-hamas/, https://www.timesofisrael.com/where-do-the-billions-of-dollars-in-foreign-aid-to-gaza-really-go/), and their schools are used to radicalize kids (https://www.australianjewishnews.com/shocking-incitement-in-unrwa-school-materials/, https://www.newsweek.com/time-endjewhatred-unrwa-schools-opinion-1654096). This has been happening for years, and what happens? Nothing. The money keeps pumping into Gaza, Hamas uses it for whatever they want, and there is no accountability, not from the UN and not from the international community. Hamas continues to incite conflict, cause both Israeli and Palestinian (when their rockets misfire and land in Gaza)  deaths, and to prevent any growth in the economy or betterment of living conditions in Gaza.

Comment: While mostly true (I don't think we can say that "most countries are super-supportive of Hamas/the PA"; Israel has a lot of back-room diplomacy with many countries that formally support the Palestinian political entities), that doesn't mean there aren't any at all.

Comment: Can you provide a source?

Comment: @zevspitz Also I'm talking about western countries (North America and Europe), not South America/Asia/the middle east.

Comment: @user253751 UNRWA schools are used as Hamas bases (https://unwatch.org/un-admits-palestinians-fired-rockets-unrwa-schools/, https://www.jpost.com/arab-israeli-conflict/unrwa-discovers-hamas-tunnel-under-gaza-schools-496394), their funds are used to build terror infrastructure (https://www.jewishpolicycenter.org/2007/08/31/how-unrwa-supports-hamas/, https://www.timesofisrael.com/where-do-the-billions-of-dollars-in-foreign-aid-to-gaza-really-go/), and their schools are used to radicalize kids (https://www.australianjewishnews.com/shocking-incitement-in-unrwa-school-materials/, 1/2

Comment: @user253751 2/2 https://www.newsweek.com/time-endjewhatred-unrwa-schools-opinion-1654096). This has been happening for years, and what happens? Nothing. The money keeps pumping into Gaza, Hamas uses it for whatever they want, and there is no accountability, not from the UN and not from the international community. Hamas continues to incite conflict, cause both Israeli and Palestinian (when their rockets misfire and land in Gaza)  deaths , and to prevent any growth in the economy or betterment of living conditions in Gaza.

Answer (score -4):

The official answer is the [Palestinian people via the electoral process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Palestinian_legislative_election). As you can see in the Wiki article, elections in Palestine are not regular events and do not follow the electoral processes used by many Western nations.  So, the ultimate answer could be argued as "Hamas" or "No one."